# Deconstruction of type in typeclass definition (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm not sure if the title is descriptive enough but I'm not very experienced in Haskell. I want to make a typeclass for two-parameter type constructors that depends on the types by which the constructor is parametrized, like

```
class MyTypeclass (ctor a b) where
  funct :: (ctor a b) -> a
```

(assuming `ctor :: * -> * -> *`, `a :: *`, `b :: *`) and, assuming I have a

```
data Pair a b = Pair a b
```

be able to do something like

```
instance MyTypeclass (Pair a b) where
  funct :: Pair a b -> a
  funct (Pair x _) = x
```

is it possible without multiple parameter type classes (because it's too powerful -- I just want to deconstruct the type my typeclass is parametrized by)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use so called "constructor classes" that take higher kinded types:

```
class C ctor where
    funct :: ctor a b -> a

instance C Pair where
    funct (Pair x _) = x

instance C (,) where
    funct = fst     -- (a,b) -> a
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. But I'm quite concerned about the amount of type inference that happens there -- how could I make two-parameter typeclass with two constructor classes? I need a way to specify which type comes from where.

Comment: Not sure I understand your concern - but remember: The class variable (here `ctor`) must appear in every class-function signature, and it must be applied to the correct number of type arguments. Hence all types are fixed trough the inputs.

Comment: More simple question then: could you give explicit type signature of `funct` inside `instance C Pair where` ?

Comment: Sure, just replace `ctor` with `Pair` in the type siganture of the class memeber.

Comment: OK, I think now I more-or-less understand it :).